# Run sql procedure and print logs

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have a sql procedure with me:

```
create or replace function db.func(value varchar) returns text as $$
        select distinct key, 
        from db.func 
$$ language SQL STABLE PARALLEL SAFE;
```

I want to execute it, i have tried:

```
EXEC db.func 'value';
db.func('value');
EXEC db.func @value='value';
```

How can i print the logs inside the procedure or is there any tool that can convert sql procedure to plain sql queries?

Comment: That looks like Postgresql to me. Why the SQL Server tag?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, my  mistake.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the procedure from shell, run:

```
SELECT db.func(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace function db.func(value varchar) returns text as $$
select distinct key, 
from db.func 
$$ language SQL STABLE PARALLEL SAFE;

print 'hello message';
```

-> After execute procedure then select tab Message on SQL SERVER Tool to see output print.

Comment: how do i execute it from shell?